# A geometry problem that involves congruence of triangles.

Tags: geometry

**The problem:** The line segments $AC$ and $BD$ intercept at $P$ such that $PA = PD$, $PB = PC$. Let $O$ be the circumcenter of the triangle $\bigtriangleup PAB$. Prove that $\overleftrightarrow{OP}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ are perpendicular.

**What I've tried:** Alright, so far I've proved that triangles $\bigtriangleup APB$ and $\bigtriangleup DPC$ are congruent, which as the most obvious thing to do first. Next I proved that triangles $\bigtriangleup APD$ and $\bigtriangleup CPB$ and both isosceles and similar. With this it wasn't hard to prove that $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CB}$ are parallel.

But... that's it. After some work I've realized that I'm pretty much stuck. I know that the circumcenter is where the perpendicular bisectors meet, and I've tried to use that fact (along with what I've already proved) to prove what I'm asked to; I've tried angle chasing, I've tried introducing some new points too, but no luck.

Would anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's segment AD in the first line, isn't it?

Comment: Oops, I've made a lot of typos. It's AC and BD. I've fixed everything now, though. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of $\triangle CPD$ and let $E$ and $F$ be the feet of the altitudes from $C$ and $D$, respectively. Then $E = HD \cap CP$ and $F= HC \cap DP$. We have to show that $O$ lies on $PH$. Let $O'$ be the intersection point of $PH$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AP$. We have $|O'P|/|AP| = |HP|/(2|EP|)$. Analogously, we have $|O''P|/|BP| = |HP|/(2|FP|)$ where $O''$ is the intersection point of $PH$ and the perpendicular bisector of $BP$. From the similar triangles $\triangle EPD$ and $\triangle FPC$ we have $|EP|/|PA|=|EP|/|PD|=|FP|/|PC|=|FP|/|BP|$, it follows that $|O''P|=|O'P|$. Since $O'$ and $O''$ lie on the same side of $P$, we have $O'=O''$. Therefore, the intersection point $O$ of the perpendicular bisectors of $AP$ and $BP$ lies on the line $PH$ through $P$ perpendicular to $CD$.

Comment: Could you explain a little further how did you conclude that $|O'P| = |O''P|$ using those 4 ratios?

Comment: We have $$|O'P| = \frac{|HP||AP|}{2|EP|}$$ and $$|O''P| = \frac{|HP||BP|}{2|FP|}.$$ From the similar triangles $\triangle EPD$ and $\triangle FPC$, we have $\frac{|EP|}{|PA|} = \frac{|FP|}{|BP|}$ or $$\frac{|AP|}{|EP|} = \frac{|BP|}{|FP|}.$$ Substituting this gives $|O'P| = |O''P|$. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that. Nice solution, thank you for your help!